# waitForLoadState('networkidle') does not work in Playwright

Tags: javascript, automation, load, playwright-test, domcontentloaded

For fully page loading I have used *waitForLoadState('networkidle')*. It works before but for now randomly error *'Error: page.waitForLoadState: Navigation failed because page was closed!'* appeared after test run.
What is the alternative for 'networkidle' state?

I have tried states 'domcontentloaded' and 'load' instead of 'networkidle' but it was not helped

Comment: share your code as well